# Count not updating on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, string-length

I have two multiselect menus where I'm trying to get a total of how many children are present in each multiselct on load, then update the numbers, based on a click event which will push from one to the other, or vice versa.

The onload portion is working fine. I'm getting the results I'd expect and the counts are accurate.

The problem I'm having is updating both counts once the click event triggers. My counts never change.

Here's my code along with a fiddle:

```
var activeUser = $('.activeUsers');
var eligibleUser = $('.eligibleUsers');
var availableUserCount = $("#availableUsers option").length;
var eligibleUserCount = $("#eligibleUsers option").length;

activeUser.html(availableUserCount);
eligibleUser.html(eligibleUserCount);

$('#availableUsers').click(function () {
    return !$('#availableUsers option:selected').remove().appendTo('#eligibleUsers');
    activeUser.length(function() {
        return availableUserCount();
    });

    eligibleUser.length(function() {
        return eligibleUserCount();
    });
});

$('#eligibleUsers').click(function () {
        return !$('#eligibleUsers option:selected').remove().appendTo('#availableUsers');
activeUser.length(function() {
        return availableUserCount();
    });

    eligibleUser.length(function() {
        return eligibleUserCount();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mujaji/8gkLyfe3/3/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you're already using Knockout, have you tried working with observable arrays to manage the lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be 3 problems with your code.

- You are using `return` in the fist line of the click event. So the following code will never be executed (`Get rid of that and only return if you cannot find any options`)
- There is no method called `length` for a div element. (`Use .text() instead`)
- When you are returning the length inside the function `return availableUserCount();` it will return you the cached value. (`You need to reselect the element again`)

So your code should technically look like this (further refactoring can still be made)

```
var activeUser = $('.activeUsers');
var eligibleUser = $('.eligibleUsers');
var availableUserCount = $("#availableUsers option").length;
var eligibleUserCount = $("#eligibleUsers option").length;

activeUser.html(availableUserCount);
eligibleUser.html(eligibleUserCount);

$('#availableUsers').click(function () {
    !$('#availableUsers option:selected').remove().appendTo('#eligibleUsers');
    activeUser.text(function() {
        return $("#availableUsers option").length;
    });

    eligibleUser.text(function() {
        return $("#eligibleUsers option").length;
    });

});

$('#eligibleUsers').click(function () {
    !$('#eligibleUsers option:selected').remove().appendTo('#availableUsers');
    activeUser.text(function() {
        return $("#availableUsers option").length;
    });

    eligibleUser.text(function() {
        return $("#eligibleUsers option").length;
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gkLyfe3/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

$("#availableUsers option").length doesn't dynamically change with the number of options. Once you set it up top, it's 40 forever. This does what you want:

```
$('#availableUsers').click(function () {
    $('#availableUsers option:selected').remove().appendTo('#eligibleUsers');
    activeUser.text($("#availableUsers option").length); 
    eligibleUser.text($("#eligibleUsers option").length); 
});
```

Although it's not efficient to re-query every time when you could do

```
availableUserCount--; eligibleUserCount++;
```

And keep track of it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Using return in the first line of the functions prevents any other code from executing in that block.

Check out my fiddle for a functionalized way to perform this

```
function setUserCounts(){
    availableUserCount = $("#availableUsers option").length;
    eligibleUserCount = $("#eligibleUsers option").length; 
    activeUser.html(availableUserCount);
    eligibleUser.html(eligibleUserCount);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8gkLyfe3/6/

Essentially, we add this function and then call it from within the click handlers, while also removing the

Comment: check your jsfiddle link (you have to click on update to create a new jsfiddle)

Comment: Oh lame, let me fix that

Answer (score 1):

Best solution (sic) :D

```
/*JQUERY FUNCTIONS*/
var activeUser = $('.activeUsers');
var eligibleUser = $('.eligibleUsers');
var eligibleUserCount = function(){eligibleUser.html($("#eligibleUsers option").length)};
var availableUserCount = function(){activeUser.html($("#availableUsers option").length)};

eligibleUserCount();
availableUserCount();

$('#availableUsers').click(function () {
    $('#availableUsers option:selected').remove().appendTo('#eligibleUsers');
    availableUserCount();
    eligibleUserCount()
});

$('#eligibleUsers').click(function () {
    $('#eligibleUsers option:selected').remove().appendTo('#availableUsers');
    availableUserCount();
    eligibleUserCount()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8gkLyfe3/5/